# keeping zeros as first characters on an input in html

Tags: html, vue.js, input

so i'm having trouble with html inputs on vue.
whenever i'm trying to type zeros as first characters, the input value changes.
so lets say im trying to type '005' it changes to '5', same for '05' it changes to '5'.
i've tried to look for it, but all the information in getting is how to do it, not how to prevent it. any ideas?

i've tried to use e.preventDefauld() but e is not defined.
i've also tried to convert the number to a string on input.

Comment: Try that one: https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpNUFtqwzAQvMqyXykkMu2ncUp7gZ5AP0q8iR0sWUirtMX47ln5kRiMmZ0RM7M74Lf36p4IS6yYrO8M06d2AC7ZE4UShmGBMI6Zr1rnE0N5N12io8ZZ1AhfkyBM8rWY/Kw8//vtOzGvik2SjPEcWs+C6c/3gaGmi0kdw5DzxMvs3mYMEIhTcOv0avn+MTNTxXGf/5a46esoG8zSttaOno4A3LRRLTsegRSbcCVW04JbV+3kq4qlLe6xtbnuwRqvbrF3csLJUy9C1PgM1yg3zrPGhtnHsiji5ZwPf4uqD9dCkArJcWtJUbSHU+h/IwUx1rim4/gAC0mR/Q==

Answer (score 0):

The following should work as you expect

```html
<template>
  number: {{ number }}
  <input :value="number" @input="updateNumber" type="number">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      number: 12
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateNumber(e) {
      this.number = e.target.value
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is [a playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpNUFtqwzAQvMqyXykkMu2ncUp7gZ5AP0q8iR0sWUirtMX47ln5kRiMmZ0RM7M74Lf36p4IS6yYrO8M06d2AC7ZE4UShmGBMI6Zr1rnE0N5N12io8ZZ1AhfkyBM8rWY/Kw8//vtOzGvik2SjPEcWs+C6c/3gaGmi0kdw5DzxMvs3mYMEIhTcOv0avn+MTNTxXGf/5a46esoG8zSttaOno4A3LRRLTsegRSbcCVW04JbV+3kq4qlLe6xtbnuwRqvbrF3csLJUy9C1PgM1yg3zrPGhtnHsiji5ZwPf4uqD9dCkArJcWtJUbSHU+h/IwUx1rim4/gAC0mR/Q==).